# Как выполнить такую расстановку блоков в css?

Tags: css, изображения, blocks

Привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие стили задать, чтобы всё стало по местам как на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через nth?

Comment: Разбить список на две колонки с расстоянием между ними 'x', задать картинку фоном для списка и расположить по центру, задать ей размер 'x'

Comment: подобные расстановки очень удобно делать с помощью bootstrap grids, если будет интересно добавлю пример в ответы

Comment: Если Вам не сложно, можете добавить?)

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, дальше уже стилизовать и разукрашивать

```css
.left-side {
   display: inline;
   width: 33%;
   float: left;
}

.center {
   display: inline;
   width: 33%;
   float: left;
}

.right-side {
   display: inline;
   width: 33%;
   float: left;
}

.main {
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='left-side'>
  1. Первый пункт <br>
  2. Второй пункт <br>
  3. Третий пункт <br>
  </div>
  <div class='center'>
  Картинка
  </div>
  <div class='right-side'>
  4. Четвертый пункт <br>
  5. Пятый пункт <br>
  6. Шестой пункт <br>
  </div>
</div>
```